# Dapper insert syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I use orm dapper from c# application for mysql database access. It works fine. There's only syntax question. I have a class with a many properties. All this properties matches database table fields exactly. So Select request is pretty short:

```
 var listOfInstances = con.Query<MyClass>("Select * From myTable");
```

but when I need to insert something into database I have to write all those properties names that looks a little bit ugly:

```
con.Execute(@"Insert into myTable values(@Id, @Property1, @Property2, @Property3, @Property4, ....)", listOfInstances);
```

I wonder if there are any shorter syntax to insert data, at least for such a case when all class properties matches database table fields exactly.

P.S. The same thing about Update request

P.P.S. If say honestly I just start to work with a database which contains many tables, so I had to write basic functions get/add/change instance for each of those tables and it is quite annoing to list all of their fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to install a nuget package called Dapper.Contrib
here's the repo
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib

Also check this out https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/01/16/that-annoying-insert-problem-getting-data-into-the-db-using-dapper